# t.format is not a function using react-datepicker and momentjs

Tags: javascript, datepicker, reactjs, browserify, momentjs

Im having an issue with react-datepicker and momentjs. From what I can see online, there are some errors with moment and browserify when using .format(), but there are no answers!

I receive the following error when I try to change the date:

Uncaught TypeError: t.format is not a function

```
onStartDateChange: function(date) {
    date = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    this.setState({ selectedStartDate: date });
},
render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.selectedStartDate}
            onChange={this.onStartDateChange} />
      </div>
      )
}
```

Has anyone seen an error similar to this? When I alert the date it is correct but the datepicker will not hide because of the error.

Comment: I'm assuming the error is occurring on the first line of `onStartDateChange`. What's the value of `date` in `onStartDateChange` when the error occurs? What does `moment(date)` return?

Comment: `date` is 1449723600000 and 'moment(date)` returns `2015-12-10` (or whatever date is selected)

Comment: `moment(date)` should return a Moment object, not a string. I may be wrong about where the error is occurring. Perhaps it's happening within the DatePicker component. Can you edit your question to include the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an issue in imports

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import moment from "moment";
```

Be careful dont use

````
import {DatePicker} from "react-datepicker";```
````

(I got the same issue with this import)